# Make mysql connection from django using option no-auto-rehash

Tags: mysql, django, database

Whenever I am connecting to remote mysql server using django, server takes lot of time for making connection. When I connect from bash using -A option it connects instantly as it does not load the metadata for the database I am connecting to.

Is there a way in django to implement the same?

Comment: are you talking about a database connection using django? And your bash connection is using ssh, or are you talking about using mysql client? From the same server?  The `auto-rehash` is purely a mysql client feature and not a generic database connection feature.

Comment: Do you have `skip-name-resolve` set?

Comment: Yes, I am making database connection using django. I tested the connection using mysql client with option -A from localhost to remote server.